# Perfect knowledge of a group with generators and identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose I have a group G, and I know the number of generators, call them A,B,C,...

If I know every single combination of generators that results in the identity element, is the group uniquely defined? For instance, if I had the generators A,B and knew that

$$A^2 = B^2 = A^2B^2 = ABA^{-1}B^3 = ... = e$$

Would I be able to identify the group?

Comment: Yes, that is called a presentation of a group see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group

Comment: Note that, typically, there are infinitely many (and perhaps uncountably) many products which equal the identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this uniquely defines the group (up to isomorphism).

Let $H$ be the set of generators that you know of: $A, B, C, \ldots$; and let $F(H)$ be the free group on $H$.

We can define an equivalence relation on $F(H)$ by saying that $a \sim b$ if and only if $a\ b^{-1}$ is one of the "combinations of generators that results in the identity element". Let $J$ be the set of equivalence classes generated by this equivalence relation.

It turns out that $J$ is well-defined as a group, and $J$ is isomorphic to $G$.